# If $G= \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ and $H= 2\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$, then the quotient group $G/H$ is isomorphic to ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

> Let $G= \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$. Let $H= 2\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$. Then, the quotient group $G/H$ is isomorphic to ...
>
> 1. $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$
> 2. $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$
> 3. $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$
> 4. None of the above

I solved out 3rd option to be the correct answer. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Incidentally, another Akshie posted a [PSQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2929777) using almost the same format.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think $3$ is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points:

- groups $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $10\mathbb{Z}$ are both abelian and of course $10\mathbb{Z}\leq2\mathbb{Z}$. So the group $H$ is defined. We see that $$H=\{\bar0+10\mathbb{Z}, \bar2+10\mathbb{Z},\bar4+10\mathbb{Z},\bar6+10\mathbb{Z},\bar8+10\mathbb{Z}\}\cong\mathbb{Z}_5$$
- With a similar way, you can find $G/H=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z_{10}}}{\mathbb{Z_5}}$.